# Query performance from date functions VS Date dimension table

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I have a table `Transactions` which has a column store index and stored 74445000 rows.

I have a query like below

```
SELECT 
  CustomerNumber,
  MONTH(CreationDate) AS m,
  YEAR(CreationDate) AS y,
  CurrencyID AS c 
FROM Transactions
```

I am mulling that may be doing a JOIN on a Date Dimension table which contains month and year for all dates may be better than the above query which uses SQL date functions.

Can anyone verify this assumption and/or point to a resource which can provide a details?

Comment: You can write another query with `join`  on a `Dimension` table and compare the performance of both the queries

Comment: Or you can create two *persisted* computed column `Month` & `year` so that you dont have to use any `Date` functions in `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any alteration of the original column will have an impact on the query performance. For the calculation of month & year in your query, you should get a very efficient Batch Execution Mode, which will make alternatives look quite pale. 
Plus, if your join will be done on an integer/bigint column, than you might be able to get Segment Elimination which should improve your query performance, but going for any string column will make query lasts incredible amount of time in comparison with the int data types. 
In another words - unnecessary headaches.

There are no big alternatives since Columnstore Indexes do not support computed columns yet (SQL Server 2016).